# Parse SDK / CocoaPods

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cocoapods, parse-server

I have an objective C iOS app using the Parse SDK.
In the process of moving this app from Parse.com to a self hosted Parse-Server, I need to update the Parse SDK to the latest version. For this update I decided to go with CocoaPods.

This is the first time I touch CocoaPods (after reading and hearing so much good about it).

I found my way, following what I could read [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) and also based on a few CocoaPods tutorial I quickly viewed.

Having my project "*ready*", when buiding it I get this error:

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>     -----> File not found.
```

Obviously things have changed place. And I tried a couple of unsuccessful solutions.

So here is my question:
**How do I need to change the settings of my project, now that I am using CocoaPods?**

Comment: What is version of cocoa pod are you using?

Comment: It is 1.1.1 (according to pod --version). Just installed it yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note that the previous answer to this question suggested Cocoapods which is [no longer supported](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/pull/1696/files).*

In order to use Parse iOS SDK you need to add it with the swift package manager. The full instructions are in [the GitHub Readme.md](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX#getting-started).

Comment: Thanks, that made me, go forward a big step. Now I don't see the error anymore. But I still have a problem though; I get this other error:
ld: framework not found ParseUI
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: please try to clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: I did it, but with no effect. I presume I need to adjust some setting.
I even retried, but I always run into the same issue.

Comment: It finally works, I also needed the line use_frameworks! (which I first did not include) and one more detail: I had to adjust LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS in the settings.

Comment: That's great ;)